# Firebird - How to use embedded server with ODBC / OleDB

Tags: odbc, oledb, firebird

I need to connect using ODBC / OleDB to a Firebird database, but without the server, so I want to install the embedded server.

I downloaded the embedded firebird server, put into database folder, renamed fbembed to gds32.dll, , then I installed IBProvider, and i was trying to create the database connection. But everytime I try to test the connection it tells me it cannot find gds32.dll.

Where I should install embedded firebird server dll's for the OldDB providrr to find them? I was trying in same folder as OldDB provider, in System32, in db folder. None worked.

I have Win7 x64 Ultimate, and I need to access that db both from a VS 2008 SSIS project, from a VS 2008 app, and maybe from a Access database, as linked tables through a ODBC connection

Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with ODBC driver.
It asks for client library, where one should select the gds32.dll from embedded server, and all workes ok.